# Nsrange problem when it should return 0

Tags: iphone, objective-c

So, I am trying to search an nsstring for a term us rangeFromString, but whenever there is not anything matching that result, I get something along the lines of 2748601949 as opposed to 0.  I am trying to, for example, locate @"sin(",@"cos(", and @"tan(" in a string like @"1+sin(28)+cos(72)". Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's returning `NSNotFound`, which is defined in `NSObjCRuntime.h` like this:

```
enum {NSNotFound = NSIntegerMax};
```

Comment: It doesn't return NSNotFound directly. It returns an NSRange. When it doesn't find the string it returns NSNotFound in NSRange.location.